# Regex looking for structs / nested structs in .c files

Tags: c#, .net, regex, recursion, struct

I want to look for Structs in  .C files and I'm using regex in c#

I have a Text like this:

```
typedef struct IsoSns_UxBuffer_tag
{
    float32  f32Val[ISOSNS_UX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint8   u8WrId;
float32  f32Val[ISOSNS_UX_BUFFER_SIZE];
struct IsoSns_UxBuffer_tag
    {
        float32  f32Val[ISOSNS_UX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        uint8   u8WrId;
        boolean bIsFull;
    }IsoSns_UxBuffer_t;

}IsoSns_UxBuffer_t;

typedef struct IsoSns_UxBuffer_tag
{
        float32  f32Val[ISOSNS_UX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        uint8   u8WrId;
        boolean bIsFull;
    }IsoSns_UxBuffer_t;
```

my Regex is:

```
(?<Struct>(struct\s+\n*(?<strName>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*\n*{[\s\n]*((?R)*|(?<Element>([a-zA-Z0-9_\s\]\[]*\n*;[\s\n]*))*)*[\n\s]*}\s*\n*(?<Alias>[a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]]*)\s*\n*;))
```

It works fine, but .net doesn't support recursive arguments like "?R".. I've read that I can solve this Problem by using balancing Groups. But I can't figure out how...

Is there maybe a better way to look for nested structs in c files by using regex?

Comment: Does each nested struct need to be separate per match, or does grabbing all of them together work?

Comment: Well, looks like this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/3543437

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)